How can I protect my desktop client from API abuse using appcheck in Firebase?
I'm trying to include extra security in my desktop application by using Firebase AppCheck tokens.
I'm developing a desktop client using React as frontend and Nodejs as backend deployed on Firebase Functions.
The client is hosted on the Overwolf client so my application has a unique custom domain format:
overwolf-extension://{CUSTOM-UID}

AppCheck - frontend
I generate the AppCheck token in frontend by using this function here:
import { getToken, initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } from "firebase/app-check";

const firebaseAppCheck = initializeAppCheck(firebaseApp, {
   provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider("RECAPTCHA-KEY-HERE"),
   isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
});

//...
{
  //...
  const { token } = await getToken(firebaseAppCheck, true);
  headers["X-Firebase-AppCheck"] = token;

  // make the request here
  // ...
}
// ...



AppCheck - backend
In the backend I have a middleware on my endpoints that checks for this token and its validity:
export const appCheckVerification = async (req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const appCheckToken = req.header("X-Firebase-AppCheck");

    // ...

    try {
      await admin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
      return next();
    } catch (err) {
          // Handle the error
          // ...
    }
};


The Issue
It works fine for my web app client, but for my desktop client sometimes it breaks with this error message:
403 AppCheck attestation failed
Am I missing something?
Because I'm wondering if this is the right thing to do or I'm just doing something wrong at this point. Now it's not giving me the same problem again, but sometimes in the past the same error randomly appeared again so I'm scared this might happen again.
I attempted to modify several key configurations on the Google Cloud Platform, as I initially suspected the issue might be related to ReCaptcha.
However, these changes had no effect.
After that, I tried extending the TTL (Time-to-Live) of the ReCaptcha key, hoping it might resolve the issue, but unfortunately, this also didn’t produce any results.
As mentioned before, this problem appears to be random and impossible to reproduce voluntarily.
